# Search and Print by Two Conditions using AWK

Tags: awk, conditional-statements, tac

I have this file:

```
         - - - Results from analysis of weight - - -
 Akaike Information Criterion   307019.66 (assuming 2 parameters).
 Bayesian Information Criterion 307036.93

                 Approximate stratum variance decomposition
 Stratum     Degrees-Freedom   Variance      Component Coefficients
 id                 39892.82    490.360         0.7     0.6     1.0
 damid                  0.00    0.00000         0.0     0.0     1.0
 Residual Variance   1546.46    320.979         0.0     0.0     1.0

 Model_Term                             Gamma         Sigma   Sigma/SE   % C
 id                     NRM_V 17633  0.18969       13.480       4.22   0 P
 damid                  NRM_V 17633  0.07644       13.845       2.90   0 P
 ide(damid)             IDV_V 17633  0.00000       32.0979      1.00   0 S
 Residual               SCA_V 12459  1.0000        320.979     27.81   0 P
```

And I Would Like to print the Value of `Sigma` on `id`, note there are two `id` on the file, so I used the condition based on `NRM_V` too.

I tried this code:

```
tac myfile | awk '(/id/ && /NRM_V/){print $5}'
```

but the results printed were:

```
13.480
13.845
```

and I need just the first one

Comment: `tac` reads the Input_file from last line towards first line, do you really want to read file like that? Because it may change the first line in output then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, I have added `exit` function of `awk` here which will help us to exit from code ASAP whenever first occurrence of condition comes, it will help us to save time too, since its no longer reading whole Input_file.

```
awk '(/id/ && /NRM_V/){print $5;exit}' Input_file
```

OR with columns:

```
awk '($1=="id" && $2=="NRM_V"){print $5;exit}' Input_file
```

---

---

In case you want to read file from last line towards first line and get its first value then try:

```
tac Input_file | awk '(/id/ && /NRM_V/){print $5;exit}'
```

OR with columns comparisons:

```
tac Input_file | awk '($1=="id" && $2=="NRM_V"){print $5;exit}'
```

Comment: @CuriousG. It will ASAP exit  from code and will NOT further process any lines which will save our time, I used it since you want to print only 1st occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `/id/` also matches `damid`. You could use the following to print the `Sigma` value only if the first field is `id` and the second field is `NRM_V`:

```
awk '$1=="id" && $2=="NRM_V"{ print $5 }' myfile
```